# how to add searchbar in dropdown?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I used dropdown and display data using *ngFor. I want to use searchbar in the dropdown.

[image]

.html code

```
     <ion-select item-end>
         <ion-option *ngFor="let list of dataa; let i= index;" (ionSelect)="pri(list,i)">{{list.USR}}</ion-option>  
</ion-select>
```

.ts code

```
ngOnInit()
{
this.COMPANY = localStorage.getItem("COMPANY");
    this._logtask.newtask(this.COMPANY).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.dataa = data;
    });
}
```

**Requirement:-** How to add search bar in dropdown in ionic

> Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `<ion-searchbar>` is just another UI component.  You should be able to just add it to your HTML and see it on the page.  Then hook a method up to the `ionInput` event and filter the list (`this.dataa`) based on what the user is typing.  The next level of improvement would likely be to use some observables here.

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but the Angular Material autocomplete component is also a decent option if it fits in with your UI.  These components can be a little clumsy to get incorporated, but they fit well with the Angular background of Ionic.

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Answer (score 0):

Ionic doesn't provide a default searching method in ion-select. But [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-with-searchbar/89255) custom component does the work. You might need to work around with css and add the page into a custom madal to make to look similar to the default ion-select options.

Credit all goes to the original creator.